# Eclipse (kepler) Dojo Widgets (drag and drop) not visibile with IBM WDT v.8.5.5.1

Tags: web-applications, dojo, eclipse-kepler

Request for you help. I am trying to use eclipse for developing a dojo based web app.
I am unable to see the dojo widgets that I can drag and drop into the Editor as per the documentation on WDT.
Is such an option ( drag and drop of dojo widgets) avaiable for ecplise (free version)?
If avaiable what set up needs to be done to make the widgets visible.

### Configuration of my setup

Eclipse: Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Kepler Service Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819

IBM WDT v.8.5.5.1

WDT file: wdt-update-site_8.5.5.1.v20131031_0202.zip

Installed on Windows 7 OS.

I have installed eclipse (kepler version from ecplise.org) and IBM WAS developer tool(https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/wasdev/entry/download). 
Created a web project using the below workflow in Eclipse.
File->New->Web Project
Project Template: Dojo toolkit.
Programming Model: Client side only.
Dojo Project Summary:
The following dojo toolkit:Dojo Toolkit SDK 1.9.0 for WebSphere
will be copied into this project location: dojo

The above work creates a project with a folder \webcontent\dojo and subfolder container dojo specific files in the explorer window.

help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

regards
Frank

Comment: I am able to see the dojo widget (drag and drop) palette. It was only visible after I created an HTML page within the project.

Comment: Feel free to delete the question then...

Comment: is it not better to keep the question as answered rather than delete it, so that it might be useful to someone else?.

Comment: Then don't answer in comments? review the site FAQ, gain reputation points and reply.

Comment: i am not able to answer the question. As per the stackoverflow rules i have to wait at least 8 hours. will do it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to see the dojo widget (drag and drop) palette. It was only visible after I created an HTML page within the project.